# Does a const pointer passed to a function copy the address and create new pointers in the scope of a function?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have been writing a few functions the accept `const char *` arguments and inside the functions I do some pointer arithmatic. For example, I wrote this quick test.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void move_ptr(const char *ptr)
{
    printf("%p -> ", ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello?";
    printf("unmoved pointer -> \"%s\"\n", str);
    move_ptr(str);
    printf("moved pointer -> \"%s\"\n", str);
}
```

The output is:

```
unmoved pointer -> "hello?"
0x4007b7 -> 0x4007b8
moved pointer -> "hello?"
```

Does this mean that all `const TYPE *` passed to functions are really copies of the passed address in the function scope?

Comment: Yes.  This is nothing to do with `const`.  All parameters are passed as copies in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler than you're making it out to be. In C, pointers are just scalar integers (often 32 or 64 bits) that *happen* to represent memory addresses. When you pass a pointer to a function, you are passing a copy of it, just like with any other value parameter. And when you change that value, that change is *not* seen by the calling function, just like with any other value parameter.

The `const` keyword on function parameters is unrelated to this property, and indicates that the value *pointed to by* the pointer won't be changed in the function.